# Conversion of data coming from the serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am working on an hardware interfacing project and building it on .net using c sharp.Here in this application i am receiving data from a serial port on hyper terminal.The data is receiving like a charm.But the problem is that it is giving me a data that is unable to read and is as follows

The data from hyper terminal is

```
D1U1201250000000085865000000S004100417001130034200820202710033000404102000004100759000080000200031004740010500097002250
```

And its meaning full form is as follows

```
Report of Sample no# 85865
WBC = 4.1x103/µL
RBC = 4.17 x106/µL
HGB = 11.3 g/dL
HCT = 34.2 %
MCV = -82.0 fL
MCH = 27.1pg
MCHC = 33.0 g/dL
PLT = + 404 x103/µL

LYM % = 20.0%
MXD % = 4.1%
NEUT % = 75.9%
LYM# 0.8 x103/µL
MXD # 0.2 x103/µL
NEUT # 3.1 x103/µL
RDW = 47.4 fL
PWD = 10.5 fL
MPV = 9.7 fL
P-LCR 22.5 %
```

I wanna ask how to covert the data that is in first form to the seconf readable form.Thanks
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like fixed size format numbers concatenated together. Use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to cut into pieces and than convert to int and scale as needed.

Something like following, assuming value at position 20 "022030" that need to be converted into 22.030:

```
var fragment = result.substring(20, 6);
var intValue = int.Parse(fragment);
var outputValue = intValue *0.001;
```